# SQL – consolidate rows after SELECT CASE statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to consolidate rows with matching IDs returning from a SELECT CASE statement. I'm using `pgAdmin 3` on a `PG-9.3.4` database.

This is what I'm getting on pgAdmin:
[image: query result]

And this is what I want to get: [image: expected result]

I've tried grouping it, or joining the result to the table itself, but din't work. Any ideas?

My query code:

```
SELECT
    CASE
    WHEN t1.material LIKE '%Refuse%'
        THEN t1.disposal
    ELSE NULL
END AS msw_disp,

    CASE
    WHEN t1.material LIKE '%Met%'
        THEN t1.disposal
    ELSE NULL
END AS mgp_disp,

    CASE
    WHEN t1.material LIKE '%Paper%'
        THEN t1.disposal
    ELSE NULL
END AS pap_disp, t1.district

FROM dsny_net t1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `Aggregate` and `Group by` to your current query should get the job done

```
SELECT Max(CASE 
             WHEN t1.material LIKE '%Refuse%' THEN t1.disposal 
           END) AS msw_disp, 
       Max(CASE 
             WHEN t1.material LIKE '%Met%' THEN t1.disposal 
           END) AS mgp_disp, 
       Max(CASE 
             WHEN t1.material LIKE '%Paper%' THEN t1.disposal 
           END) AS pap_disp, 
       t1.district 
FROM   dsny_net t1 
GROUP  BY t1.district
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as alternative:

```
select
  district,
  unnest(array_agg(disposal) filter (where material like '%Refuse%')) as msw_disp,
  unnest(array_agg(disposal) filter (where material like '%Met%')) as mgp_disp,
  unnest(array_agg(disposal) filter (where material like '%Paper%')) as pap_disp,
from dsny_net
group by district;
```

Using `max` will drops all other values (if any) except max.

However `unnest(array_agg(disposal) filter (where material like ...)) as ...` can be replaced by `max(disposal) filter (where material like ...) as..` to make query shorter.